# How to find a malicious TCP program using netstat

Tags: linux, netstat

I am trying to do a homework for a lab but have a quick question.

How do I find a malicious TCP service that is still running and the adversary has achieved persistence by creating a systemd service?

I think I have to use netstat to find the name of the malicious TCP service, but what command should I use to find that service?

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

`netstat -tlape`

running this will show all *(**-a**)* processes *(**-p**)* currently listening *(**-l**)* on a TCP port *(**-t**)* with extended information *(**-e**)*

**note(s):**

- you need to run this via `sudo` to see everything on the system.
- use linux `man` pages when you're not sure how a program operates. in this instance you would type `man netstat` to learn more about the netstat command. to search within the man pages, press `/` and enter a `<search term>` then press `enter` to find the results. `n` will cycle forward while `N` cycles backwards.

Comment: +1. This is a good answer on the use of nestat, but as I stated in my answer, netstat can't tell you which process is malicious.

Comment: > "I think I have to use netstat to find the name of the malicious TCP service, but what command should I use to find that service?" -- i believe i answered OP's question as stated above with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Netstat can show you the owning process, but it can't tell you if that process is malicious. Netstat on it's own cannot give you what you're looking for.